# How to express "the" in Chinese

Tags: usage

I'm trying to convey the sentence "我不会好好发音四个声调" But that more directly translates as "I cannot pronounce four tones well" which is a bit ambiguous... that begs the question, which four tones? I'm sure anyone I say this to would understand but it doesn't sit well with me. In English it is easy, I'd say "I cannot pronounce **the** four tones well" which implies the existence of exactly 4 tones, all of which I have trouble pronouncing. So far I have not seen a Chinese equivalent?

Comment: First thought **the** could be translated to **這**, sometimes is equivalent to **this**

Comment: 普通话的四声, or 普通话的声调, or even just 声调

Comment: mā (妈) má (麻) mǎ (马) mà (骂) ma (吗) <- 4 tones or 5 tones?

Comment: this Chinese sentence is grammatically incorrect. 发音 is a noun, you can say 我不会好好发四个声调, and 好好 sounds wired here too, because this way, it's very subjective, and it sounds like you don't want to pronounce the four tones correctly. I would simply not use 好好 （我不会发四个声调）, or just say 我发不好四个声调

Comment: @sylvia I just threw this sentence together and even I doubted it was grammatically correct but somehow nobody corrected it until now lol

Comment: @sylvia I would just say 我发不了声调, since it's implied with proper context (like just saying it in Chinese by itself) that the 声调 are Chinese.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definite article has no equivalence in Chinese. Its functions, however, can be found in Chinese.

1. Something previously mentioned or known

Compare:

He is a murderer. 他是**个**杀人犯。(杀人犯 is **a murderer**, a man that has commited murder. 个 is like the indefinite article.)

He is the murderer.

By using nouns inherently specific.

他就是凶手。(凶手 is **the murderer** , it cannot be used without context.
他是个凶手(incorrect))

By using demonstratives: 这/那/这些/那些/此/彼

他就是这个杀人犯。

2. Something unique or identified by the speaker, terminologies.

I cannot pronounce the four tones well.

我发不好**四声**。(平上去入(tradition)/阴阳上去(modern mandarin), as a whole isn't referred as 四个声调)

Particularly, these sets of similar things are usually referred without measure words.

四书/十三经/六艺/五行/四君子/十八罗汉/一百零八星宿......

Unique things, such as the sun, the moon... are referred exactly its name (Actually the definite article is unnecessary semantically)

As for "I want to go to a/the park", it's not hard to appreciate that 我想去公园。 already fully conveys the two possible interpretation, depending on the listener.

Comment: In a general sense, is the inclusion or exclusion of a measure word (个 for instance) the difference between definite and indefinite quantities? For instance, 我有三书 vs 我有三本书, would the former translate as "I have the 3 books" and the latter translate as "I have 3 books" or is the former just grammatically incorrect? An example I found online is "三书六礼" (aka Three Letters and Six Etiquette) or is this an exception because it is a proper noun?

Comment: @小奥利奥 我有三书 is incorrect. The measure word shouldn't be dropped there.

Comment: This kind of abbreviation is just for proper nouns. "I have three books."我有三本书。 "I have the three books"我有那三本书。/三本书我有。

Answer (score 3):

**The** is rarely explicitly expressed in Chinese. Like the comments mentioned below your question, the closest equivalent is going to be a combination of 这 (this) or 那 (that) and the appropriate measure word. You might notice Chinese ESL speakers struggle with definite articles in English and that is because similar usage is not found in Chinese.

---

As for the specific sentence you’re trying to write, you’re better off with saying something more general like:

- (我的)口音很重
- (我)说话不标准
- (我说话)有点洋腔洋调的
- (我的中文)说得不好

Answer (score -1):

Seems you have the same problem as me! :(

I cannot pronounce the four tones well.
我不能准确地发音四个声调。